# Java Syslog logging to local machine only with logback

Tags: java, udp, slf4j, logback, syslog

I need to log events to the `syslog` on the localhost **only**. My first trial was with the `logback` `SyslogAppender`, but it looks like it writes the logs through UDP. The problem is that the `syslog` daemon needs to be configured to access remote logging, which i can't guarantee on all deployment targets. Is there any way to log to `syslog` "directly" ( the way `/bin/logger` would do it) from JAVA? ( i mean, without needing to go through UDP or TCP)

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you could invoke /bin/logger directly, but you would need to write a new adapter to do so.  The "easiest" thing could be subclassing the current adapter to get all the scaffolding and only override the snippet sending the message.

You may want to do some experiments on whether you can write a simple Java program invoking /bin/logger, to see if this is a viable way.

Comment: Thought of that,  but this would "tie" me to /bin/logger, which was something i wanted to avoid .

Answer (score 0):

Just across similar issue and found [SysLog4J](http://www.syslog4j.org/). Unfortunately it has not been actively developed since 2011.

Some alternative packagings exist - this seems to be fresh and alive: https://github.com/Graylog2/syslog4j-graylog2

Edit: A bit better answer is already part of the following question: [Using Syslog's unix socket with Log4J2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053768/using-syslogs-unix-socket-with-log4j2) :)