# Using Syslog's unix socket with Log4J2

Tags: log4j, logback, log4j2, syslog, syslog4j

I would like to send the logs of an application on a rsyslog server using the client protocol : Unix socket.
Both application and rsyslog server are on the same machine.

I've been comparing different logging tools : Log4J, Logback and Log4J2.

[Log4J's Syslog appender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SyslogAppender.html) doesn't permit it natively. A solution is to use [Syslog4J](http://www.syslog4j.org/) and configure our [Syslog4JAppender](http://syslog4j.org/docs/javadoc/org/productivity/java/syslog4j/impl/log4j/Syslog4jAppender.html) this way :

```
<appender name="mySyslogAppender" class="org.productivity.java.syslog4j.impl.log4j.Syslog4jAppender">
    <param name="protocol" value="unix_socket" />
    ...
</appender>
```

Same as Log4J, [Logback's Syslog appender](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/net/SyslogAppender.html) doesn't permit it natively. A solution is to use Syslog4J and [logback-syslog4j](https://github.com/papertrail/logback-syslog4j) tool, and configure our appender this way :

```
<appender name="mySyslogAppender" class="com.papertrailapp.logback.Syslog4jAppender">
    <syslogConfig class="org.productivity.java.syslog4j.impl.unix.socket.UnixSocketSyslogConfig">
            ...
    </syslogConfig>
</appender>
```

Now I'm looking for a solution for Log4J 2, but I didn't find any.
Do you know one ?
Do these tools will include natively this functionality ?